# How should i handle scope within many nested anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a Collection in mongodb, which contains embedded referenced documents, which forces me to run thought multiple anon functions.

First i initialize this array

```
  var player = {
    name : '',
    life : 10,
    gold : 50,
    score : 0,
    clientId : socket.id,
    playerId : data.playerId,
    deck : []
  };
```

Now i need to add data to the deck, by fetching data from mongodb.

```
// First find the player. 
  var playerCol = db.collection('Guest');
  playerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(data.playerId)}).toArray(function(err, playerRes) {
    // Traverse and load each tower in deck.
// Traverse each embedded reference, so each can be fetched.
playerRes[0].deck.towers.forEach(function(tower) {
  // fetch data for tower.
  towerCol = db.collection('Tower');
  towerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(tower.oid)}).toArray(function(err, completeTower) {
    // Add the tower data to the deck.
    player.deck.push(completeTower.pop());
  });
});
```

Now the problem is that the player array is still as it was, when it was first initialized. Why doesn't my data in player persist? Well i know why, because it's in another scope when not called inside a anonymous function. But how should i approach adding my values to the player array?

The snippets in one piece.

```
// Initialize the player.
var player = {
  name : '',
  life : 10,
  gold : 50,
  score : 0,
  clientId : socket.id,
  playerId : data.playerId,
  deck : []
};

// Load players deck.
var playerCol = db.collection('Guest');
playerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(data.playerId)}).toArray(function(err, playerRes) {
// Traverse and load each tower in deck.

playerRes[0].deck.towers.forEach(function(tower) {

  towerCol = db.collection('Tower');
  towerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(tower.oid)}).toArray(function(err, completeTower) {
    player.name = "Melvar";
    player.deck.push(completeTower.pop());
    console.log(player.deck); // Prints the data, just pushed
  });
});

console.log(player.deck); // Prints empty array.
process.exit(1);
```

Comment: The closures and data looks OK (I don't see that you're redeclaring the `player` variable in a nested scope). Where are you checking the player array's values? It would need to be after the completion of the call to the towerCall.toArray finishes (after the `push` call).

Comment: But deck is, and if do a console.log(player) after the push, the value is indeed there.

Comment: @martin yes spotted that and deleted comment before I saw your comment

Comment: @WiredPrairie If i console.log the player object after the push, the value is there. But if i move the console.log out of the playerCol.find function, the data is gone.

Comment: You'll need to post a bit more code if this doesn't help: The only place where the `console.log` of the values will work is at the end of the `tower.find` call. As it's all async (that's why there are callbacks), you'll need to wait till all of that work has completed. If you just `log` the value after the `playerCol.find` function, it will always be empty (as the other code won't have returned yet).

Comment: @WiredPrairie i just posted the actual snippet. So what you are saying, is that the player.deck will be set eventually? And that the console.log is proccesed, as the request to the db is going on? But i thought js was one threaded? meaning it would have to wait.

Comment: Posted an answer rather than continuing comments as I wanted to paste in a bit of code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Node.JS is single threaded, it's based on events. Do work and wait for other work to complete. Waiting for a MongoDB call to return is a perfect example of something that can be "waited" upon. In this case, it means that while the Node process is waiting for a response, it can execute other JavaScript code. Eventually, MongoDB responds, and the code is executed at the next "wait for other work" opportunity.

Marked as #1 below, the code executes before the `playerCol.find` returns. Node.JS and the MongoDB drivers are asynchronous. This means that the results of calling `find` aren't returned until **after** the initial call is made. Later, when the database has responded with the values, the callback is made. In the first call to `playerCol.find`, the callback is the inner function declared with in toArray. I've renamed it to `findPlayerAsync.`

So, right after the find is executed, the next line that runs is the `console.log(player.deck)`. If you add a marker string as shown `after find:`, you'll see that value is displayed on the console before the other `console.log` executes (marked as #2).

```
// Load players deck.
var playerCol = db.collection('Guest');
playerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(data.playerId)}).toArray(function findPlayerAsync(err, playerRes) {
// Traverse and load each tower in deck.

playerRes[0].deck.towers.forEach(function(tower) {

  towerCol = db.collection('Tower');
  towerCol.find({'_id' : new ObjectId(tower.oid)}).toArray(function findTowerAsync(err, completeTower) {
    player.name = "Melvar";
    player.deck.push(completeTower.pop());
    console.log('Inside towerCol.find: ' + player.deck); // #2 Prints the data, just pushed
  });
});

console.log('After find: ' + player.deck); // #1 Prints empty array.
process.exit(1);
```

I'd expect the console to be:

```
After find: []
Inside towerCol.find: [......]
```

Comment: Thank you WiredPrairie, this is very explaining. While this makes good sense, i still struggle on how i should i approach it. Can i force it to wait for the database request in any way? or is there a way i can do a mongodb query, without using a async callback?

Comment: You might want to look at a library like [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) for node.